# Trying to put a box around a collection of subfigures

Tags: subfloats, framed, ieeetran

I'm trying to have a bounding box around the following figure:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{center} 
\subfigure[Process with no error]{\label{noerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{noerror-process}}
\subfigure[Process with syntactic  errors (connector having multiple incoming edges and presence of hanging node)]{\label{synerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{synerror-process}} \\
\subfigure[Process with deadlock]{\label{deadlock}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{deadlock-process}}
\subfigure[Process with lack of synchronization]{\label{lacksync}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{lacksync-process}}
\end{center} 
\caption{Different kinds of errors occuring in InFlux Processes}
\label{processes}
\vspace*{-0.65cm}
\end{figure}
```

Can you please help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Note that we like to see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which are complete and compilable, not just code snippets. This gives people the possibility to easily compile your example and to add and test their solution.

Comment: You can use the package `tcolorbox` or `framed`.

Comment: Should the caption be inside the frame or outside?

Comment: Also see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651) to learn why you should use `\centering` instead of `center`.

Answer (score 9):

The following example shows possibilites with the package `framed`, `tcolorbox` and `adjustbox`.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\section{Package \texttt{frame}}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\begin{framed}
\centering
\subfigure[Process with no error]{\label{noerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{noerror-process}}\qquad
\subfigure[Process with syntactic  errors (connector having multiple incoming edges and presence of hanging node)]{\label{synerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{synerror-process}}

\subfigure[Process with deadlock]{\label{deadlock}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{deadlock-process}}\qquad
\subfigure[Process with lack of synchronization]{\label{lacksync}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{lacksync-process}}
\caption{Different kinds of errors occuring in InFlux Processes}
\end{framed}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\section{Package \texttt{tcolorbox}}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\centering
\subfigure[Process with no error]{\label{noerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{noerror-process}}\qquad
\subfigure[Process with syntactic  errors (connector having multiple incoming edges and presence of hanging node)]{\label{synerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{synerror-process}}

\subfigure[Process with deadlock]{\label{deadlock}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{deadlock-process}}\qquad
\subfigure[Process with lack of synchronization]{\label{lacksync}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{lacksync-process}}
\caption{Different kinds of errors occuring in InFlux Processes}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\section{Package \texttt{adjustbox}}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,frame}
\centering
\subfigure[Process with no error]{\label{noerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{noerror-process}}\qquad
\subfigure[Process with syntactic  errors (connector having multiple incoming edges and presence of hanging node)]{\label{synerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{synerror-process}}

\subfigure[Process with deadlock]{\label{deadlock}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{deadlock-process}}\qquad
\subfigure[Process with lack of synchronization]{\label{lacksync}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{lacksync-process}}
\caption{Different kinds of errors occuring in InFlux Processes}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to add a *frame* around such elements (note that *bounding box* and *box* in general do mean something else with LaTeX, i.e. do not imply a drawn line).

The simplest way is to use the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text only

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{adjustbox}{varwidth=\textwidth,fbox,center}
    \subfigure[Process with no error]{\label{noerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a}}
    \subfigure[Process with syntactic  errors (connector having multiple incoming edges and presence of hanging node)]{\label{synerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-b}} \\
    \subfigure[Process with deadlock]{\label{deadlock}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-c}}
    \subfigure[Process with lack of synchronization]{\label{lacksync}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image}}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Different kinds of errors occuring in InFlux Processes}
\label{processes}
%\vspace*{-0.65cm}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

You can also use `varwidth` and `\fbox{..}` directly to avoid the need for an extra package:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text only

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
    \subfigure[Process with no error]{\label{noerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a}}
    \subfigure[Process with syntactic  errors (connector having multiple incoming edges and presence of hanging node)]{\label{synerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-b}} \\
    \subfigure[Process with deadlock]{\label{deadlock}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-c}}
    \subfigure[Process with lack of synchronization]{\label{lacksync}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image}}
\end{varwidth}}
\caption{Different kinds of errors occuring in InFlux Processes}
\label{processes}
%\vspace*{-0.65cm}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Finally, you can also avoid the `varwidth` package if you are willing to calculate the required width yourself. Then you can use `minipage` directly.
This is needed in order to box the content for the frame while still allowing for line breaks:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text only

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3.05in}%
    \subfigure[Process with no error]{\label{noerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a}} 
    \subfigure[Process with syntactic  errors (connector having multiple incoming edges and presence of hanging node)]{\label{synerror}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-b}} \\
    \subfigure[Process with deadlock]{\label{deadlock}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-c}} 
    \subfigure[Process with lack of synchronization]{\label{lacksync}\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image}}
\end{minipage}}
\caption{Different kinds of errors occuring in InFlux Processes}
\label{processes}
%\vspace*{-0.65cm}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

There are also other packages for this, e.g. `mdframed`.

Comment: What should I do if I want to add a frame around only the subfigures, but not around the full figure?