# How to create protocol flows inside a centred box?

Tags: floats, framed

Could you please give some directions how to create the following  figure in latex? It is the situation of describing a two parties protocol centered in a box.
It is like a 3X4 table but i have difficulties with the alignment. Tikz is the only way for drawing this?
[image: figure 3]

Comment: See: [Trying to put a box around a collection of subfigures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55640/55644#55644) The basic command is `\fbox`.

Comment: In my opinion your question is really bad. Why don't you upload some images to demonstrate your request? In the moment I only see links where the helper must scroll.

Comment: Yes, and if you have to add PDF links please in the form `[<title>](<url>)` which is much more readable.

Comment: It would be nice if you would add an example image. Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to add new float or caption types ("Scheme" in this case) is the `newfloat` package which is part of the `caption` bundle. There is also the `float` package which also provides the `H` (for: place really Here!).
The box can be produced by using `\fbox{\begin{minipage}{<width>}..\end{minipage}}` or, more simpler, using the `adjustbox` package.

The actual content seems to be best made using a `tabular`, if you want the same format as in the PDFs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=los,
    listname=List of Schemes,
    name=Scheme,
    placement=H,
    within=section,
]{scheme}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\blindtext

\begin{scheme}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=.6\linewidth,fbox,center}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \bfseries Encryption:  & .... \\
                         & .... \\
  \bfseries Deccryption: & .... \\
                         & .... \\
            something    & .... \\
                         & .... \\
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Some scheme}
\end{scheme}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

---

[image: Result]

---

Or, using [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) v0.9 from 2012/05/16 (available on CTAN and [on Bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/downloads)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=los,
    listname=List of Schemes,
    name=Scheme,
    within=section,
]{scheme}

\usepackage{adjustbox}[2012/05/16]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\listofschemes

\section{Test}
\blindtext

\begin{adjustbox}{tabular={rp{.4\linewidth}},fbox,center,caption={Some scheme},nofloat=scheme}
  \bfseries Encryption:  & .... \\
                         & .... \\
  \bfseries Deccryption: & .... \\
                         & .... \\
            something    & .... \\
                         & .... \\
\end{adjustbox}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Change the `nofloat` to `float` if you want the scheme to float.
You can of course create a new environment for this if you need it more often.

```
\newenvironment{xscheme}{\adjustbox{tabular={rp{.4\linewidth}},fbox,center,caption={Some scheme},nofloat=scheme}\bgroup}{\egroup}
```

Don't call it `scheme` because that environment is used internally.

Comment: How can i install the `newfloat` package? i am working on kile.

Comment: @curious: Kile is just the frontend/editor. Can I assume you are using Ubuntu? Maybe with the standard Ubuntu TeX Live 2009 installation? In this case you should install TeX Live 2011 manually: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) or see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: I successfully installed tex live 2011 from [here](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) running the `install-tl` script. I then exported the path using `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH` i re-opened kile but i am getting the same error: _! LaTeX Error: File `newfloat.sty' not found._ when i run pdflatex. How am i sure the kile is compliant with the new installed packages?

Comment: @curious: Kile is just the editor, it isn't affected by the (not) installed packages. Check if you installed the package: `tlmgr install newfloat` or maybe `tlmgr install caption`. Also make sure that the right `pdflatex` is used. Maybe Kile is configured to use absolute paths?

Comment: That's what i am asking for.How i can add the installed packages to kile. I know what kile is. After running `tlmgr install newfloat`. _tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/systems/texlive/tlnet
TeX Live 2011 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release._ What do use for the above code that you posted?  which program and how do you run it? Do you know where the caption,newfloat packages are at your system?So complicated for a simple graph... I will skip if it is so time consuming

Comment: TeX Live 2011 is currently frozen because of the upcoming 2012 release. However, `newfloat` is part of it and should be still installable. Just ignore the message. Check if `newfloat.sty` is under `/usr/local/texlive/2011`, e.g. use `find /usr/local/texlive/2011 -name newfloat.sty`. If it is there and it still doesn't work then Kile is still using the wrong PATH. Try setting it in a command line window and start Kile from the same window afterwards.

Comment: I am using the `fullpage` package and the boxes' width are the same with the text width, which is huge.How can i define the box width in terms of not exceeding for instance 2cm?

Answer (score 0):

I was also interested in creating protocol flow diagrams (also known as ladder diagrams, or sequence diagrams). I found this to be the closest to what I wanted:

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sequence-diagram/

But it was far over-complicated and the code was ugly. Here's my go at a more simple form:

```
% Agents
\def\Client          {Client}
\def\MasterController{Master Controller}
\def\FeatureCtlr     {Feature Controller}

% Drawing centred nodes macro.
\newcommand{\nd}{\node(0, 0)}

% Diagram
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\normalsize,
                                       minimum height=0.5cm,
                                       minimum width=0.5cm}]

  % Matrix
  \node[matrix, very thin, column sep=1.3cm, row sep=0.5cm](matrix) at (0,0)
  {
    \nd (\Client)   {}; &          & \nd (\MasterController)   {}; &         & \nd (\FeatureCtlr)   {}; \\
    \nd (\Client 0) {}; &          & \nd (\MasterController 0) {}; &         & \nd (\FeatureCtlr 0) {}; \\
    \nd (\Client 1) {}; & \nd {};  & \nd (\MasterController 1) {}; &         & \nd (\FeatureCtlr 1) {}; \\
    \nd (\Client 2) {}; & \nd {};  & \nd (\MasterController 2) {}; &         & \nd (\FeatureCtlr 2) {}; \\
    \nd (\Client 3) {}; &          & \nd (\MasterController 3) {}; & \nd {}; & \nd (\FeatureCtlr 3) {}; \\
    \nd (\Client 4) {}; & \nd {};  & \nd (\MasterController 4) {}; &         & \nd (\FeatureCtlr 4) {}; \\
    \nd (\Client 5) {}; & \nd {};  & \nd (\MasterController 5) {}; &         & \nd (\FeatureCtlr 5) {}; \\
    \nd (\Client 6) {}; &          & \nd (\MasterController 6) {}; & \nd {}; & \nd (\FeatureCtlr 6) {}; \\
  };

  % Agents labels
  \fill
    (\Client)           node[draw,fill=white] {\Client}
    (\MasterController) node[draw,fill=white] {\MasterController}
    (\FeatureCtlr)      node[draw,fill=white] {\FeatureCtlr};

  % Vertical lifelines
  \draw [dotted]
    (\Client)           -- (\Client           6)
    (\MasterController) -- (\MasterController 6)
    (\FeatureCtlr)      -- (\FeatureCtlr      6);

  % Blocks (Budget constraints)
  \filldraw[fill=black!17]
    (\Client           0.north west) rectangle (\Client           5.south east)
    (\MasterController 0.north west) rectangle (\MasterController 3.south east)
    (\FeatureCtlr      1.north west) rectangle (\FeatureCtlr      2.south east)
    (\FeatureCtlr      4.north west) rectangle (\FeatureCtlr      5.south east);

  % Horizontal flows (inter-process).
  \draw [-latex]        (\Client           0) -- node [midway,above]{$request$}  (\MasterController 0);
  \draw [-latex]        (\MasterController 1) -- node [midway,above]{$validate$} (\FeatureCtlr      1);
  \draw [-latex,dashed] (\FeatureCtlr      2) -- (\MasterController 2);
  \draw [-latex,dashed] (\MasterController 3) -- (\Client           3);
  \draw [-latex]        (\Client           4) -- node [midway,above]{$access$}   (\FeatureCtlr      4);
  \draw [-latex,dashed] (\FeatureCtlr      5) -- (\Client           5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Sample Protocol Flow Diagram]