# Inserting figures in triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to insert small icons (figures.jpg/png) in a triangle. I have this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{bluedeep}{RGB}{0, 13, 51}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=bluedeep,line width=0.5mm] (0,6) -- (7,6) -- (7,8) -- (0,8) -- (0,6);
\draw[color=bluedeep,line width=0.5mm] (0,4) -- (7,4) -- (7,6) -- (0,6) -- (0,4);
\draw[color=bluedeep,line width=0.5mm] (0,2) -- (7,2) -- (7,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,2);
\draw[color=bluedeep,line width=0.5mm] (0,0) -- (7,0) -- (7,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following result:
[image]

I want to have a figure like this:
[image]

The small icon encircled with black pen is a figure on the hard disk that I have to add using \includegraphics. For your sake just pick any icon you want but it has to be added using \includegraphics because in my case I have specific icons to add to these boxes.
Additionally all small rectangles should have a label just as I have shown in the figure by encircling using red pen.

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Where is the triangle that appears in the title of your question?

Comment: Related: [Trying to put a box around a collection of subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55643/124842)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\includegraphics` in a `\node`, e.g. `\node at (x,y) {\includegraphics{filename}};`, and knowing that it's just a matter of picking the right coordinates.

I used some loops to add text and images, if all icons are different, and the positions are not meant to be regular, use separate `\node` commands, with appropriate coordinates.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % loads pgf and graphicx
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\definecolor{bluedeep}{RGB}{0, 13, 51}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [bluedeep, line width=0.5mm] (0,0) rectangle (7,8);
\foreach \y in {2,4,6}
   \draw (0,\y) -- (7,\y);

\foreach [count=\i] \txt in {
  Text A,
  Text B,
  Text C,
  Text D}
  \node[below] at (3.5,\i*2) {\txt};

\foreach \y in {1,3,5,7}
  {
   \node at (1.5,\y) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}};
   \node at (3.5,\y) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}};
   \node at (5.5,\y) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-c}};
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cheers. Just what I needed.